# How can I properly load my scene from another with a button click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 scenes, 'scene1' and 'scene2', first, i had to switch from scene1 to scene2, it worked perfectly by adding 'Load Level On Click' to the button in scene1 [(see it here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKCJk.png)

Now from scene2 to scene1, this time by clicking on an UI Button on scene2, i'm using OnClick() and a script called 'LoadScene' [(see it here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWB6X.png),
here is my simple script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;

public class LoadScene : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start()
    {
    }
    void Update()
    {
    }
    public void Load () {   
            SceneManager.LoadScene("scene1");
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is when i click the button (in scene2) to switch to scene1, it works but i lose a lot of elements on the scene1 like buttons and images.

I don't really know where does the problem come from !! Is there something to add to my script so i can load my scene correctly?

Comment: The issue is that you want to have your scene1 right like you left it or you want the scene1 to be like a new one when you come again from scene2? Or you are missing gameObjects from a brand new scene1 when you come from scene2?

Comment: Yes @camaron I want to have scene1 right like I left it